# iteration over Array finds method added to prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays

I set up the following addition to Array:

`Array.prototype.intersection = function(other) { return this.filter(x => other.indexOf(x) >= 0);}`

Later I iterate over an array, similar to the following:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
(3) [1, 2, 3]
for (let j in a) console.log(j)
VM30274:1 0
VM30274:1 1
VM30274:1 2
VM30274:1 intersection
undefined
```

The definition for the Array.keys method says

> Object.keys() returns an array whose elements are strings corresponding to the enumerable string-keyed property names found directly upon object. This is the same as iterating with a for...in loop, except that a for...in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well. The order of the array returned by Object.keys() is the same as that provided by a for...in loop.

so I understand why 'intersection' shows up here, and that I should iterate over keys() or some other such way. But why does only 'intersection' show up, and not other Array prototype methods like 'push' or 'pop'? Are predefined methods treated supposed to be differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for...in`, the mdn doc states that `The for...in statement iterates over all enumerable string properties of an object`. And, to determine whether a property is enumerable or not, we can use `Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable()`, e.g. `Array.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable('intersection')`.

Now, if we check on the `push` and `intersection` properties, we can see that `push` returns false and `intersection` returns true, which mean one is not enumerable and the other one is enumerable.

To make `intersection` non-enumerable, we can also use this code, in which the `enumerable` option is default to false. And when you retry again, the loop will not output the `intersection`.

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'intersection', {
  value: function(other) { return this.filter(x => other.indexOf(x) >= 0);}
});
```